# Spam from my server

Tags: spam, exim

I have exim and dovecot on my server installed with directadmin. Some users use it to send spam.

How can i disabled this and remove my server from abuse.

info from mainlog

> 2010-07-07 13:00:16 1OWSEF-0002aw-Gh => info  F= R=virtual_user T=virtual_localdelivery S=2252
>   2010-07-07 13:00:16 1OWSEF-0002aw-Gh Completed

and from message headers

```
1OWSbZ-000315-FM-H
mail 8 8
<ishasanya@hotmail.com>
  1278501353 0
  -helo_name snt0-omc1-s49.snt0.hotmail.com
  -host_address 65.54.61.86.43647
  -host_name snt0-omc1-s49.snt0.hotmail.com
  -interface_address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  -received_protocol esmtp
  -body_linecount 32
  -max_received_linelength 405
  -deliver_firsttime
  XX
  1
  info@****.com

  216P Received: from snt0-omc1-s49.snt0.hotmail.com ([65.54.61.86])
  by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with esmtp (Exim 4.69)
  (envelope-from <ishasanya@hotmail.com>)
    id 1OWSbZ-000315-FM
    for info@****.com; Wed, 07 Jul 2010 13:15:53 +0200
    147P Received: from SNT101-W13 ([65.55.90.9]) by snt0-omc1-s49.snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4675);
    Mon, 5 Jul 2010 04:49:07 -0700
    058I Message-ID: <SNT101-W139D12A2ED9AE344214C04B8B10@phx.gbl>
      035* Return-Path: ishasanya@hotmail.com
      088  Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
      boundary="_98a72e16-f4ad-4040-b007-d6c101b0731b_"
      036  X-Originating-IP: [182.114.208.252]
      045F From: isaac shasanya <ishasanya@hotmail.com>
        028T To: <info.sto.pl@stoeu.com>
          059  Subject: =?gb2312?Q?Dear_Frien?= =?gb2312?B?ZDog0OnS4L+o?=
          037  Date: Mon, 5 Jul 2010 11:49:07 +0000
          019  Importance: Normal
          018  MIME-Version: 1.0
          084  X-OriginalArrivalTime: 05 Jul 2010 11:49:07.0384 (UTC) FILETIME=[13115380:01CB1C38]
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks this is an inbound email. It's not sent from your server, but from hotmail.com

> Received: from snt0-omc1-s49.snt0.hotmail.com

Look the direction, the email was sent to the user info.., I guess it means info.sto.pl@stoeu.com and it is your user, right?

> OWSEF-0002aw-Gh => info
>
> 045F From: isaac shasanya 
>           028T To:

Answer (score 0):

How about spam filters?

http://marc.merlins.org/linux/exim/sa.html

http://johannes.sipsolutions.net/Projects/dovecot-antispam

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Outbound Email Security service](http://www.safentrix.com/outbound). This will make sure that your users cannot mis-use your server to send SPAM.

Answer (score 0):

If they target your users with Spam, install a Spam filter (as in James Santiago's post)

If your server is being used to send spam to other users you might be running an open relay.

Comment: +1 - I agree check that your only serving mail for authorised users!